# Is it preferable to add properties to a Node module.exports object, or replace the object entirely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Which of these patterns is preferable in Node, and why?

Replacing the `module.exports` object entirely;

```
module.exports = {
  myFuncOne = function(thing) {
    console.log(thing);
  },
  myFuncTwo = function(stuff) {
    console.log(stuff);
  }
}
```

Or, adding properties to the existing `module.exports` object;

```
module.exports.myFuncOne = function(thing){
  console.log(thing);
};

module.exports.myFuncTwo = function(stuff){
  console.log(stuff);
}
```

Are both the same for all intents and purposes other than preference, or is there a more significant difference that could have implications here?

Comment: It only matters if you have circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-true way of doing it, my advice is simple: Be consistent.

In node.js docs, all examples are just adding properties to existing exports object: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html

The exception is a case, when you want to export just a function (a constructor perhaps) - then you are forced to use `module.exports = ...`

Some argument about extending existing exports instead of overriding it may be less work for Garbage Collector. Node.js module system will create an empty exports object for you anyway. So when you are overwriting it, GC has to collect the unused object created by module system.

The main difference is, that "`exports`" is just an alias for existing `module.exports = {}` object.
When you are adding properties to `exports`, you modify existing object. When you assign new value to `exports` the `exports` alias is no longer pointing to module.exports (it is now pointing to the value/object you have assigned to it and this will not be exported).

Comment: That makes sense. Are there (or could there be) any properties added to the object created by the module system that could be lost by overriding that object?

Comment: Yes, according to https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object the module object has: id, exports, parent, filename, loaded and children properties. 

If you log properties of module, you will see that there is also "paths" property, but I don't see it in documentation. It contains all paths that will be used to resolve requires.

Comment: Well, that's the module object, but what about module.exports?

Comment: exports is empty object with prototype set to Object.prototype, exactly like `var o = {};`. You can safely assign any property to it.